# Asciidoctor / RevealJS default CSS generated

Tags: javascript, reveal.js, asciidoc, asciidoctor-revealjs

I'm launching asciidoctor via a javascript API & gulp.

```
const options = {safe: 'unsafe', backend: 'revealjs', attributes: { 'stylesheet': 'custom.css' }};
asciidoctor.convertFile(file.path, options, );
```

But generated HTML still get the default CSS generated :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/reveal.js/dist/theme/black.css" id="theme">
  <!--This CSS is generated by the Asciidoctor reveal.js converter to further integrate AsciiDoc's existing semantic with reveal.js-->
  <style type="text/css">
    .reveal div.right {
```

I've also tried lots of asciidoc tags ( customsheet & so on) but nothing works.

FYI :

```
> npx asciidoctor-revealjs --version
Asciidoctor reveal.js 5.0.0-rc.1 using Asciidoctor.js 2.2.6 (Asciidoctor 2.0.17) [https://asciidoctor.org]
Runtime Environment (node v18.2.0 on win32)
CLI version 3.5.0
```

Thx for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally succeed to do what I need, I'm not able to detail why but it is about order in the first slide.

My solution was to put :customcss: flag after fist slide content.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the reveal.js theme using `:revealjs_theme:` or override it using `:revealjs_customtheme:`.

See: https://docs.asciidoctor.org/reveal.js-converter/latest/converter/revealjs-options/

Comment: I known this option but I'd like to customise the "ascidoctor css generated part".

Answer (score 0):

As @mogztter answered, you need to use `:revealjs_theme:` or `:revealjs_customtheme:`.

> I known this option but I'd like to customise the "ascidoctor css generated part".

If I might be so bold, that is not what you want to do.

I think you want to customize the presentation provided by RevealJS's CSS with your own CSS, which is not the same goal as customizing the Asciidoctor CSS.

Let's assume that you've setup your converter per [the documentation](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/reveal.js-converter/latest/setup/node-js-setup/).

There are two additional steps:

1. Create your custom CSS file, say `mystyles.css`:

   ```
   @import "node_modules/reveal.js/dist/theme/black.css";

   /* add your custom CSS styles here */
   ```

   Adjust the `@import` declaration to use the RevealJS theme stylesheet that you want.

   Add your desired styles.
2. Add `:revealjs_customtheme: mystyles.css` immediately below the document title.

Now, when you run your converter script, the `mystyles.css` file is loaded. It, in turn, loads the RevealJS theme CSS, and then applies your custom styles. Your styles can adjust or replace RevealJS styles as needed using CSS conventions.